# Non-square layout

Tags: wpf, panel

I'm trying to make a certain layout in wpf, the best way to explain is to show you:

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

And it should look like this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this in wpf? The borders need to be exactly like in the image.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean with rounded edges, or the not-full-height second column?

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil I updated the image, hopefully it's clearer now. My question is how to accomplish the weird shaped panel 1

Comment: Are controls supposed to flow into the pan-handle of `Panel1`? Or does `Panel2` live in the air space above `Panel1`, covering controls under that region.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Well, it doesn't really matter how it's done, as long as the borders look like the sample image and I can still place my controls anywhere I want. At the moment the "pan-handle" is a seperate panel which I want to attach to the big panel 1 on the left so it looks like one big "pan-shaped" panel.

I uploaded a second image to show what I have now and it's contents.

Comment: @Jesse: your actual image explains it better than your Panel1/Panel2 image. You actually have 3 separate panels you wish to *look like* 2 panels.

Comment: @sixlettervariables exactly! I could have explained that better... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are grids you can fake it 99.9% of the way with two `Border`s which have their Width set to the `CornerRadius` and bind their height to the `ActualHeight` of the top right panel:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Border Background="Red" Grid.RowSpan="2" CornerRadius="5" Margin="2"/>
  <Border x:Name="TopRight" Background="Red" Grid.Column="1"
          CornerRadius="5" Margin="2"/>
  <Border Background="Yellow" Width="5"
          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopRight}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,2,0,2"/>
  <Border Background="Yellow" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TopRight}"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,2,2,0"/>
  <Border Background="Green" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
          CornerRadius="5" Margin="2"/>
</Grid>
```

The colors in this are for example of the overlaying only.

Comment: Wow, that's works really nice! Although the inner corner is not rounded I really like the result, thanks!

Comment: If you mess around with Clip properties, you might be able to remove that square corner... but it might take a lot of messing around and fill the XAML with lots of Geometries. The last 5% taking 95% of the work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
<Grid>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Control x:Name="Panel1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" />

  <Control x:Name="Panel2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />

</Grid>
```

You could play around with the column/row ratios as required (or use fixed values).

(And of course use what you you want instead of `<Control />`s)

Comment: Using this method I can't make the borders look like my example, that's the most important thing to me.